# Passing Data between View Controllers (yes, I know... )

Tags: ios, objective-c

Yes, I know that this question is very popular here and has been given a lot of answers to this question, and yes,  I was here [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers/9736559#9736559). But I can't do it for a long time.

in ViewControllerB.h I create a property for the BOOL

```
@property(nonatomic) BOOL *someBool;
```

ViewControllerA.m:

```
#import "ViewControllerB.h"

ViewControllerB *viewControllerB = [[ViewControllerB alloc] init];
viewControllerB.someBool = YES;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewControllerB  animated:YES];
```

In ViewControllerB.m ViewDidLoad:

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.someBool);
```

But xCode give me error on this line ( NSLog(@"%@", self.someBool);)  and say: `Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code =2)`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @rokjarc Why are you suggesting that this be moved to a singleton? There is no basis for such a suggestion in this case.

Comment: @rmaddy: ok, i admit i'm exaggerating a bit. But this particular case is just a part of the bigger app. I believe there is no place for data in views or controllers. The sooner people learn to use MVC, the less questions on passing data between viewcontrollers will be :)

Comment: @rmaddy: but yes, it was a bad suggestion. i'm removing it.

Comment: @rokjarc While I agree that proper use of the M in MVC is important, view controllers do have their own state and properties. Not everything belongs in the model.

Comment: True. I got carried away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your property is a pointer. It shouldn't be. Change this:

```
@property(nonatomic) BOOL *someBool;
```

to:

```
@property(nonatomic) BOOL someBool;
```

The log should be:

```
NSLog(@"%d", self.someBool);
```

Only use `%@` with objects.

Comment: BTW - it is important to understand why and when you use a pointer and why and when you don't. You don't in this case because `BOOL` is a native type and not a class. Except for very rare conditions, when you define a property, never use a pointer for native types and of course you must use a pointer with object types.

Answer (score 2):

Declare it as a `BOOL`, not a *pointer to a* `BOOL`:

```
@property(nonatomic) BOOL someBool;
```

Answer (score 1):

You either need to declare it as a primitive and get rid of the * or store it as an object by wrapping it as an `NSNumber`

`@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *someBool`

Then you'd write `someBool.boolValue` to grab its value